# Trying to create a scrollable cell?

Tags: html, css, cell, css-tables

I have a table that has one cell that will be receiving much more input than other cells.
I want to be able to **scroll** the **cell** horizontally so that each cell in the table does not get bigger in order to accommodate that cells content.

```
<div class = "Table">
   <div class = "Row">
      <div class = "Cell">Name</div>
      <div class = "Cell">Info</div>
      <div class = "Cell">A lot of content, content, content, content, content</div>
      <div class = "Cell">Phone Number</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is an example of the table I keep getting:

```
 +-----+-------+----------------------------------+
 | Jon | 45.45 | somecontent,      | xxx-xxx-xxxx |
 |     |       | somecontent,      |              |
 |     |       |   somecontent     |              |
 |     |       | ,somecontent      |              |
 +-----+-------+-------------------+--------------+
```

Is there any way I can make the third cell **scrollable**? So that no matter how much input is placed in it all other cells will remain unscathed?

Here is an example of what I want:

```
+-----+-------+---------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Jon | 45.45 | somecontent,somecontent,somecontent,somecontent.. | xxx-xxx-xxxx |
+-----+-------+<--------------------___SCROLLBAR____---------->---+--------------+
```

There is nothing special about my css at the moment:

```
 .Table{ display: table ; }
 .Row{display: table-row; }
 .Cell{display:table-cell ;}
```

Here is a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/DJXvD/

Comment: Why are you using `div`s for what seems to be tabular data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
<div class = "Table">
    <div class = "Row">
        <div class = "Cell">Name</div>
        <div class = "Cell">Info</div>
        <div class = "Cell"><span>A lot of content, content, content, content, content, 
                                  content, content, content, content...</span></div>
        <div class = "Cell">Phone Number</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's CSS:

```
.Table { 
    display: table ; 
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.Row{
    display: table-row;
}

.Cell{
    display:table-cell;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.Cell > span {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Comment: To make it more generalizable, I've removed the nth-of-type() selector.  This way, any cell that has content wrapped in a span is presumed to require a scroll bar on overflow.

Answer (score 1):

This is a work-around to table-cell display

http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/5wbur/13/

**HTML**

```
    <div class = "Table">
   <div class = "Row">
      <div class = "Cell">Name</div>
      <div class = "Cell">Info</div>
      <div class = "Cell scrollable">A lot of content, content, content, content, contentA lot of content, content, content, content, contentA lot of content, content, content, content, content</div>
      <div class = "Cell">Phone Number</div>
   </div>
    <div class = "Row">
      <div class = "Cell scrollable">A lot of content, content, content, content, contentA lot of content, content, content, content, contentA lot of content, content, content, content, content</div>
      <div class = "Cell">Name</div>
      <div class = "Cell">Info</div>
      <div class = "Cell">Phone Number</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.Table{ display: table ; }
 .Row{display: table-row; }
 .Cell{width:100px;display:inline-block;float:left;height:50px;border:1px solid red;}
.scrollable{ overflow-x:scroll; white-space:nowrap;}
```

Comment: this will probably do the trick, I was afraid that by getting rid of `display: table-cell` it would ruin the whole layout. I will wait before voting you for best answer, but if no one else knows has a better method I will vote. Thank you so much my friend. +1

Comment: @BryanFajardo OK, anyway if you woul adopt this work-around, remember to clear fix ;)

Answer (score 1):

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TyFWu/

CSS:

```
.Table {
    display: table;
}
.Row {
    display: table-row;
}
.Cell {
    width:100px;
    ddisplay:table-cell;
    float:left;
    padding: 10px;
    background: yellow;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
.test {
    overflow-x:scroll;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="Table">
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell">Name</div>
        <div class="Cell">Info</div>
        <div class="Cell test">A lot of content, content, content, content, contentA lot of content, content, content, content, contentA lot of content, content, content, content, content</div>
        <div class="Cell">Phone Number</div>
    </div>
```

You could get it done through `display:block;` way but the height will be longer and it wouldn't align the text properly

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/TyFWu/1/

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to reset as `block` the `div` you want to scroll and set a proper `height` or `max-height`.**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DJXvD/1/)** or **[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/DJXvD/2/)**

```
div:nth-child(3) {
     display:block;
     height:3.2em;
     overflow:auto;
 }
```

or

```
 div:nth-child(3) {
     display:block;
     max-height:2.6em;
     overflow:auto;
 }
```

and for an horizontal scroll : http://jsfiddle.net/DJXvD/3/